# Episerver-Filter Blocks from a Page

Tags: episerver

I am creating a schedule job to set some property of blocks. One of the condition is to exclude them which belongs to a particular page. For Instance ,I need to filter out Hero blocks from Article pages for some sites.

**Updated Answer**

```
          var contentType = _contentTypeRepository.Load(typeof(HeroBlock));

            var heroBlockContentReferences = _contentModelUsage.ListContentOfContentType(contentType)
                .Select(contentUsage => contentUsage.ContentLink.ToReferenceWithoutVersion()).Distinct()
                .Select(contentReference => contentReference).ToList();

            foreach (var siteDefinition in _siteDefinitionRepository.List())
            {
                                var heroBlocksWithinArticlePages = new List<HeroBlock>();

                var startPage = _contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(siteDefinition.StartPage);
 
                //Filter hero block content references site wise
                var heroBlocks = heroBlockContentReferences
                    .Where(contentReference => _siteDefinitionResolver.GetByContent(contentReference, true, true).Name == siteDefinition.Name)
                    .Select(contentReference => _contentRepository.Get<HeroBlock>(contentReference)).ToList();

                if (!heroBlocks.Any())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (startPage.ThemeName.Equals("ABC"))
                {
                    var articlePages = _contentLocator.GetAll<ArticlePage>(startPage.ContentLink);
                    foreach (var articlePage in articlePages)
                    {
                         
                            var filteredHeroBlocks = articlePage.MainContentArea.FilteredItems
                                .Select(contentItem => _contentRepository.Get<IContent>(contentItem.ContentLink))
                                .Where(content => _contentTypeRepository.Load(content.ContentTypeID).Name.Equals("HeroBlock"))
                                .Select(contentReference => _contentRepository.Get<HeroBlock>(contentReference.ContentLink));

                            heroBlocksWithinArticlePages.AddRange(filteredHeroBlocks);
                         
                    }
                }

                foreach (var heroBlock in heroBlocks.Except(heroBlocksWithinArticlePages))
                {
                    var writableCloneHeroBlock = (HeroBlock)heroBlock.CreateWritableClone();
                  //Set the property that needs to be set
_contentRepository.Save((IContent)writableCloneHeroBlock, EPiServer.DataAccess.SaveAction.Publish, EPiServer.Security.AccessLevel.Read);
                
                }

             }
```

Any input is appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing your `ArticlePage` type has some `ContentArea` properties that `Hero` blocks can be added to? If so, why not just look for `Hero` blocks for each page in `filteredArticlePages`?

Comment: Thanks Ted. Yes I was trying to look for the same but was missing the right casting. Got it right & its working

Comment: Great! I'd suggest posting your code as an answer, or remove the question.

Comment: Updated the answer for the question above